How to iterate across columns to find intersection in R?
I have a data.frame in R which has more or less this structure:
structure(list(F1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA), F2 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA
), F3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

(my actual data.frame is about 600k rows and 120 columns).
What I want is to extract the intersection across a column and the previous one. This code works perfectly in my dummy data.frame:
library(foreach)

foreach (i=2:ncol(test)-1) %do% {

    base::intersect(test[,i+1], test[,i])

    } -> test_ii

[[1]]
[1] NA  2  3

[[2]]
[1] NA  4

[[3]]
[1] NA

When I try to apply this to my actual data.frame, I get just one no-empty list and a bunch of empty lists:
List of 116
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ p12-2014: num [1:597462] 1400004 1400005 NA 1400009 1400010 ...
 $ : list()
 $ : list()
 $ : list()
 $ : list()
  [list output truncated]

I guess this is because the volume of the data but I can't figure out some solution to improve my code. Being said that, I appreciate any comment or advice.

What output do you expect? Are there actually shared elements between columns 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc.?

Map(intersect, df[-ncol(df)], df[-1]) ? But that should be doing the same thing as your loop essentially.

One possibility is that your real data is not a pure data.frame (maybe tbl or data.table), so that data[, i] doesn't return a vector but a structured column. You can use class(data) to check this.

I think @DarrenTsai is correct. If you convert your test data frame to a tibble: test <- tibble(test), and run the code again, you get an empty list .

Also, see this post, second answer, and this one, which suggest adding , drop=TRUE].

Instead of using single square brackets (which would behave differently between pure data.frame, tibble, and data.table) for selecting a column within the loop, use double square brackets. So, change the expression base::intersect(test[,i+1], test[,i]) to base::intersect(test[[i+1]], test[[i]]) and try again.

@DarrenTsai You were right. I coerced to data.frame and it worked fine. Thank you!

@Jan Not similar but the solution was as simple as coerce my DB to data.frame. If you think this should be closed or deleted, please let me know. Thanks in advance.
